# Java: setting an icon in a jar application

Tags: java, jar, icons

I've developed an application that I export into a runnable jar (including the libraries it needs). Everything works fine.

When running the app from Eclipse I'm able to change the icon that the application window shows:

```
BufferedImage image = null;
try {
   image = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource("AT42.png"));
} catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
this.setIconImage(image);
```

The picture is placed in my .class files directory.

When I run it from Eclipse it shows the icon, but when I create a runnable jar and execute it I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
        at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
        at com.tools.at4.UserInterface.<init>(UserInterface.java:43)
        at com.tools.at4.GeneradorInformes.main(GeneradorInformes.java:8)
        ... 5 more
```

I guess the icon is not include in the jar file, my question is, is there any way of incluiding it, so that when I run the jar file the windows that are created show my icon instead of the Java cup?

Thanks!!

Comment: Jar file is just zip archive, open it and check.

Comment: Hi dedalo.  How are you creating the JAR file?

Comment: +1 Matt. Exactly, how are you creating your jar file? Are you using Eclipse' own creating executable jar aka 'Export' feature or your custom ANT script or simply using jar command? In using Eclipse feature, just include your png alongside the java source and it should get included.

Comment: Hi, I go to File --> Export --> Runnable Jar file. Then I choose the option: package required libraries into generated jar.
Thanks!

Comment: I'm using the export feature. My png file is placed where all the .class files are. Where should I place the png file? Thanks

Comment: Try placing png files along side .java files and see if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

With the path you are using your image needs to be put at the root of your jar file. Assuming you have your image in a directory in your project called "images", this ANT task would put the image(s) at the root of your jar:

```
<target name="construct-jar" depends="compile,javadoc">
    <copy todir="${build.dir}">
        <fileset dir="images"/>
    </copy>
    <jar destfile="${dist.dir}/${jar.name}" basedir="${build.dir}"/>
</target>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I put the file where the .class files are I should modify my code like this:

```
image = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource("/AT42.png"));
```

Thanks!!